# I want to create a Server on a Dell T5400 with two processors

Tags: raid

After watching many YouTube videos, I find that the Ubuntu website is not user-friendly, at least to this user.  I have used Mint on another computer; but I want to try to create my own server.  I can't figure out how to choose the right options in the download section.  I asssumed that my Dell would be able to handle the job; but the four options for downloading Ubuntu Server stop me before I can get anything done.  I am trying to use a RAID configuration.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I suggest using the [Ubuntu Serverguide](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs), in particular the [installation - storage -raid section](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/install/storage).

Comment: should work just fine

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers, everyone.  My question was actually about how to simply download Ubuntu.  The screens presented matter that confused me.  Technical terms that are of no interest to me were presented as if they had something to do with my download. I didn't expect that in the Linux world; but I am reminded that Canonical is a business.  So my apologies if I have wasted anyone's time.  I think I did finally do the download correctly.  The things that confused me were not related to my reasons for being on the download page.  Thanks to the person who offered the links.  They are helpful.  Have a great day everyone.